# jquery - Trigger first row of Datatable without row ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I am trying to trigger first row of datatable without row ID. I can easily do this with row ID but the problem arises when the table is ordered with a different column than the default. The row ID may disappear due to pagination of the datatable.

Suppose I have 40 rows in a table and there are 8 pages of 5 rows each. The first row ID is on the top by default and it is easy to trigger it with row ID. But if the table is ordered according to some other column than default, then the first row ID may not be present on the first page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not clear with the question. Are you able to share your code?

Comment: @JollyJose In simple words, you have a Data-table and you have to click the first row. How'd you do it?I can't share the code but take the default datatable as example. https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this to click the first row of a table `$("#tableID>tbody>tr:first").trigger('click');`